# Outputting a string result from a list

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of items of a custom data type Film = String String Int, where the strings are the name and director and Int is the year of release.

What's the best way I would go about making a function that outputs a String or set of strings (doesn't matter how long) which show the information like:

Title: (film title) Director: (director) Released: (released)

Comment: What have you already tried? What does not work?

Comment: I'm trying to get started really, i'm thinking of using recursion to get it to repeat until it's done but i'm stumped on how to syntax it.

Comment: You just need a function to transform a `Film` to a `String`. Then you could use `map` to transform a list of `Film`s to a list of `String`s.

Comment: There are [many good tutorials](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tutorials) available around the web.

Comment: You shouldn't need recursion to show one Film. Try to start by writing a function that shows just the title in the format you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a function that creates a String if given a Film as 
an input, e.g.:

```
data Film = Film String String Int

instance Show Film where
  show (Film t d r) = 
      "Title: (" ++ t ++ ") Director: (" ++ d ++ ") Released: (" ++ show(r) ++ ")"
```

You can read up on type classes and user-defined `show` [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html) and [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html).